# how to solve 401 error in react native web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I am trying to make an axios get request but am receiving 401 everytime am trying to fetch. However am already logged in as I have previously received my user login response
My project has been built with react native init and is running on browser using react-native-web.
The same api when I check the response on mobile and postman it is giving the correct response however on browser it is throwing 401
below is my axios code

```
useEffect(() => {
    let url = `${ROOT}/children/${id}/vaccinations`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log("Hello", res);
        setData(res.data.content);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

The response of 3 apis that are being called
[image]

The error that am receiving
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

could anyone please tell me where am going wrong?
any help would be appreciated.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Qyf.png

Answer (score 0):

401 code error means you are not authorized, you would need to send your user token that you receive from the backend as a header when sending your specified request, something like that:

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/user', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': ${access_token}
  }
})
```

You can read more about sending tokens in headers via this link:
https://flaviocopes.com/axios-send-authorization-header/

I hope this helps in solving your issue.